# How to display DateTimeIndex x_tick labels

Tags: pandas, plot, series

I have a Pandas series with a DateTimeIndex that I'm plotting as a line plot.  I'd like my x_ticks and x_tick labels to only be the DateTimeIndex of the series.

Using the code below I'm displaying the x_ticks I want, but I'm also getting both 'Jan 2019' and 'Feb' added to the x_tick labels, as well as the values 30 and 10 at each end of the x-axis (which are the day values of the first and last DateTimeIndex).

```py
w_c = pd.date_range(start=pd.to_datetime('2018-12-30'), end=pd.to_datetime('2019-02-10'), freq='w')
sales = [111.94, 193.44, 143.46, 157.26, 124.8, 206.26, 127.22]
test = pd.Series(sales, index=w_c)

fig,ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8,7))
ax = test.plot(fontsize=10, color='darkorange', lw=0.8, ylim=(0,250))
ax.xaxis.grid(True, which="both")

ax.xaxis.set_ticklabels(test.index.strftime('%d/%m/%Y'), rotation=25, minor=True)

display(fig)
```

Can someone tell me how to remove these additional labels?  I expect the x_tick labels to be the DateTimeIndex in my test Series only.

See screen shot here with unwanted labels circled in red

[image: img]

Answer (score 0):

One quick solution is to plot the

```
w_c = pd.date_range(start=pd.to_datetime('2018-12-30'), end=pd.to_datetime('2019-02-10'), freq='w')
sales = [111.94, 193.44, 143.46, 157.26, 124.8, 206.26, 127.22]
test = pd.Series(sales, index=w_c)

fig,ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8,7))

# plot on ranks of rows instead of index
ax.plot(range(len(test)), test, color='darkorange', lw=0.8)
ax.set_ylim(0,250)
ax.xaxis.grid(True, which="both")

# manually modify the label
ax.set_xticklabels([''] + test.index.strftime('%d/%m/%Y').to_list(), rotation=25)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for that.  I just needed to change the final line to:

```ax.set_xticklabels(list(test.index.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')), rotation=25)```

and it works.  Seems like a crazy thing to need to do!